# I have created a form in Access that corresponds to a table with zero attributes

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created a form in MS Access. The corresponding tables for these forms have zero attributes. I simply created a blank form and manually inserted text boxes, labels, check boxes, etc. Now I would like to capture specific information that is entered into the form. How would I go about this in MS Access? Do I need to write some VB code to say "record whatever value the user puts in the field for serial number" for example? There is no preexisting data in any tables.

A user will manually fill out the form in Access, I would like to capture the data that the user inputs.

Comment: How are you going to use the data that is captured? Are you having users enter information in a table to be stored and manipulated later? If so, Gustav's answer is appropriate.

If you are using what the user enters to select in a query or report, You need to have the query or report reference the form in the selection criteria, and usually VBA code would open the query from a form command button. Let us know more of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the table to the form and then bind the controls to the fields of the table.

Or, the easy route: Mark the table in the navigation pane, then click in the band: **Create** and then **Form**, and it will do the dirty work.

Comment: How does one bind the controls to the fields of the table?

Comment: That's the reason for the suggested easy option: Run that and study the generated form.